# Angular: applying filters to a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to apply a filter to an array, so as it changes in the JS, it changes back in the HTML (due to the two-way-binding). This is the controller I'm using:

```
app.controller('controlador1', ["filterFilter", "$scope", function(filterFilter, $scope) {

   this.array = [
    {name: 'Tobias'},
    {name: 'Jeff'},
    {name: 'Brian'},
    {name: 'Igor'},
    {name: 'James'},
    {name: 'Brad'}
  ];
  var active = false;
  $scope.applyFilter = function(){
   if(!active){
    $scope.arrayFiltrado = filterFilter(this.array, "a");
    active = true;
   }else{
    $scope.arrayFiltrado = this.array;
    active = false;
   }
  }
  $scope.arrayFiltrado = this.array;

}]);
```

Also, this is my HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="miApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="mainmodule.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
<body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="controlador1">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="applyFilter()">button</button>
 <span ng-repeat="elem in arrayFiltrado">{{elem.name+" "}}</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to apply/deactivate the filter when I click the button, but no matter what I do, if I click the button, nothing shows at the HTML. It's like if the array got erased.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Would need to see the `filterFilter`

Comment: The filter works properly. If I just apply a single filtering action at the beginning, it works. The problem appears once I launch the ng-click option, which makes the list of names to dissapear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only angular binding to do it. 
It avoid to much code on your controller and simplify logic.

JS

```
app.controller('controlador1', ["filterFilter", "$scope", function(filterFilter, $scope) {
    $scope.active = false;

    $scope.arrayFiltrado = [
        {name: 'Tobias'},
            {name: 'Jeff'},
            {name: 'Brian'},
            {name: 'Igor'},
            {name: 'James'},
            {name: 'Brad'}
        ];

    $scope.filtering = function(item) {
        if(!$scope.active) {
            return true;
        }
        return item.name.indexOf('a') !== -1;
    }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="controlador1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="active = !active">button</button>
    <span ng-repeat="elem in arrayFiltrado | filter:filtering">{{elem.name+" "}}</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code works great, indeed! So I see I can't bind data to a normal JS element, but to an angular's element?

Comment: The main issue comes from 'this' : it is context dependant. You should avoid using it (until you switch to ES6 ;) because it is not the same 'this' into your controller and into applyFilter function. Just use 'var array' or '$scope.array'

Answer (score 0):

If your filter working properly then instead of `this.array` you should use `$scope.array`

```
$scope.array = [....];
```

and

```
$scope.arrayFiltrado = filterFilter($scope.array, "a");
$scope.arrayFiltrado = $scope.array;
```